# Destruction of a capital world

Tags: society, science-fiction, economy

So for a story I'm doing, I have a war in which the deciding battle destroyed Earth, which is the capital of the "Terran Republic." Subsequently, they are forced into unconditional surrender, handing over a fair chunk of territory to their enemies. My question is this:

What would be the economic impact of such an event be?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please try to stitck to 1 question per post. Now you have 4. And also try to limit the scope of your question, as they are now I have the feeling they are too broad, and we basically cannot do all the work related to your story for you.

Comment: Sorry. Basically, if a nation's capital was destroyed, what would be the economic impacts? That's what I'm most concerned over. I can infer the rest.

Comment: Please use the edit button to rephrase your question, then.

Comment: Your last comment is a clearer statement than your post!  You might like my [Lessons for Writing Good Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/lessons-in-writing-questions).  Your comment contains what should be the **lede** of your question post: “if a nation's capital was destroyed, what would be the economic impacts?”

Comment: It seems that the feedback is forcing me to address things I hadn't thought about at first. But yes. I'll take a look at these lessons.

Comment: What was the economic position of your Earth in your Republic? In some countries (like Netherlands) formal capital is *not* a key part of the economy and does *not* even house government.

Comment: As you now have at least 5 reputation and can therefore post on [Meta] I want to tell you about our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). It's a way to test a question and get feedback on general things such as on-topic/off-topic, grammar, possible duplicates, missing information, formatting, etc. before releasing a question onto the Main Site. Just a tip in case you want to give it a try at some point in the future. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn mroe about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

## Your decision for your story

Some people say that Europe would do better without Brussels, and that the US would do better without Washington. *I believe these people are wrong,* they are underestimating the benefits of economic and regulatory coordination.

## They surrendered, right?

If the loss of the homeworld caused the Earthlings to surrender, there are some possible explanations:

- It was a psychological turning point, turning a war-weary population to surrender. The economic effects were minimal.
- The economy was arranged so that the capital planet provided [key goods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Raid_on_Schweinfurt) and services.
- The capital planet did provide a large percentage of GDP.

But I think one can say that **if** the surrender of the homeworld did cause the surrender of mankind, **of course** there will be major economic dislocations. Even if the theory in the first paragraph is right, and the colony worlds will do better without micromanagement from the capital, there will be temporary problems as they get into the new way of doing business.

---

*Follow-Up:* Some ideas for the average guy:

- No more bugfixes for computer operating systems; the programmers and the source code went up in smoke.
- No more brain surgeons will graduate from homeworld universities, ever.
- The colonial goverment decides unilaterally that all student loans owed to the homeworld are now owed to *them*, and repayment starts *now*.
- Two colonial goverments take it on themselves to update the industrial standard for *whatever*, gizmos are now incompatible.

Comment: The biggest thing I'm wondering is how such an event would affect the average person. Would it be more recession or great depression. And yes, it was a valuable world. High population, and seat of the government officials.

Answer (score 1):

This could usher in a golden age or it could doom all of the Terran people.

It really depends on the republics relationship with Earth. Were the other planets of the republic totally dependent on Earth? Was Earth repressing them? Was Earth just a tourist destination that provided nothing but traditional ceremonies?

Without knowing the relationship to Earth, really it could cause anything to happen. Maybe the whole galaxy is going to commit suicide since now they'll never see the last season of Game of Thrones.

> The people usually had a decently positive view of the government. Freedom is considered a fundamental right. And they've been leading the nation to expand their territory, bringing with it an influx of new resources - [Alex Russet the Snivy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84134/destruction-of-a-capital-world/84138?noredirect=1#comment247177_84138)

Sounds fairly liberal. Population centers tend to be. Likely the rest of the republic isn't so populous. Without their liberal influence the republic likely  becomes conservative and starts harboring bitter resentment towards their enemies. This could become xenophobic to the point of ethnic cleansing occurring in Terrans remaining territories. Before you know it people start believing in eugenics and talking about the pure Terran race. Then we're off and running to replay world war II on a galactic scale.

Comment: Earth was the seat of the government. Sort of the republic's D.C. Plus it was very populated.

Comment: That doesn't answer the relationship question. Seats of government can be supportive, oppressive, or irreverent. Sometimes all three and the only place in the galaxy to get a good hotdog.

Comment: The people usually had a decently positive view of the government. Freedom is considered a fundamental right. And they've been leading the nation to expand their territory, bringing with it an influx of new resources.